# Dynamically generate proc files?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm making a linux kernel module and I was wondering if there was a way to dynamically generate proc files and use them in a sensible way.

I have no problem creating a struct with a `list_head` and going from there, but my ultimate problem is that I want to have the exact same function execute with different variables. Namely, I just want to have a `write_proc` that ends up writing to a different buffer in kernel memory for each file (and a `read_proc` that reads from the same).

The reason I'm having difficulty with this is that the function protoypes for reading/writing from proc files don't seem to allow this behavior:

```
int read_proc(char *buf, char **start, off_t offset, int count,
              int *eof, void *data) {

int write_proc(struct file *file, const char *buf,
               unsigned long count, void *data) {
```

Now, I can statically create a bunch of functions and just make sure that I allocate enough, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Here's an example of how I would want it to look in userland (I don't have a code MWE since I have no idea where to even begin):

```
$ echo "file1" > /proc/mydir/create
$ echo "file2" > /proc/mydir/create
$ ls /proc/mydir
  create  file1  file2
$ echo "1" > /proc/mydir/file1
$ echo "5" > /proc/mydir/file2
$ cat /proc/mydir/file*
  1
  5
```

Have I just gone off the deep end?

I'm looking for quite generic compatibility (2.6.33+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my ultimate problem is that I want to have the exact same function execute with different variables.

I assume you are already able to create the /proc files then. As [Ilya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16148142/912144) said, `create_proc_entry` does the job (even though there is a better alternative).

> The reason I'm having difficulty with this is that the function protoypes for reading/writing from proc files don't seem to allow this behavior

Well actually it does. If you look at the prototype of either function:

```
int read_proc(char *buf, char **start, off_t offset, int count,
              int *eof, void *data);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^

int write_proc(struct file *file, const char *buf,
               unsigned long count, void *data);
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You will see a parameter called `data` which is a generic `void *`. Using this parameter, you can make the same function work with different variables.

Now `create_proc_entry` is not the best function for this. In fact, there is a replacement for it<sup>1</sup>, which also matches a better naming scheme for /proc functions. Looking at [the source code itself](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/generic.c#L708), you can see the signature of `create_proc_data` and how it works. Using this function, you can provide the pointer to the working area of the /proc file. This pointer will be passed to both your read and write functions.

This is very similar to how `pthread` work for example, and many other libraries that take function pointers as callbacks.

---

<sup>1</sup> If I'm not mistaken, `create_proc_entry` is deprecated.

Comment: I recommend looking at the implementation of /proc through the link I provided. It's very simple and quite informative. In fact, it's easier to read through that and use it, than to try to find information from incomplete documentation or outdated blog posts.

Comment: Thanks so much, sorry for the delay in accepting the answer, I haven't had much time to play with this lately. For some reason, the `data` thing totally slipped my mind even though it was staring me in the face! Thanks again for all the details and links!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for `create_proc_entry` function. It can create a proc entry in a run time. See the [details](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/generic.c#L695) here, for example.